# Why are my data augmented images losing pixel color?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

So I was trying to apply data augmentation on a given image by using the following code:

```
import cv2


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, img_to_array
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255,
                             shear_range=0.2,
                             horizontal_flip=True,
                             vertical_flip=True,
                             zoom_range=[0.6,1.0],
                             fill_mode='nearest',
                             data_format='channels_last',
                             brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])

IMG_SIZE = 230
img_array = cv2.imread('rgb.jpg') 
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
print(new_array.shape)     # (230, 230, 3)
x = img_to_array(new_array)
x = x.reshape((1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
print(x.shape)       # (1, 230, 230, 3)

t = cv2.imwrite('rgb_original.jpg', new_array)
print(t)      # True

for _ in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1, save_to_dir='img_test', save_format='jpg'):
    break
```

However the resulting image seems to be losing some of its colors when compared to the original image as we can see below:

[image: 'rgb.jpg']            <----- This is the 'rgb.jpg'

[image: 'rgb_original.jpg']    <----- This is the 'rgb_original.jpg'

[image]      <----- This is the image resulting from data augmentation

I think my problem resides in the reshaping line, however I dont understand why it is happening since I use all 3 color channels. Does anyone have any idea of what might be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have the RGB channels in reverse order for OpenCV, which wants them as BGR.

Comment: Hi! You are right. This line 'new_array = cv2.cvtColor(new_array, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)' solved it. Thanks!